# Is there an idiom for a puzzle in which changing one attribute changes the other, so that you have to account for multiple factors?

Tags: idiom-requests

Say you have conditions A, B, and C.

You want them all to be at a certain threshold, but if you increase A, C decreases. Change B, and both A and C change. The factors are linked to each other. I'm wondering if there's a term for this type of situation.

Comment: Sort of *chain reaction* or *domino effect**?

Comment: I feel like that implies a series of events that happens in order, while I'm looking for something to describe a noun - an object that has dependent factors, and is difficult to solve because of it.

Comment: These are simply dependent factors.

Comment: I can't put my tongue to a word.  I might use **compound** for a quality close to what you describe,  "compound knot of a puzzle" ?  Here are some more words (3 pages, this is the middle) related to labyrinthine http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/labyrinthine/2  .. also "knotty" alone has it's merits

Comment: It's a Chernobyl puzzle.

Comment: "An intricate system"?

Comment: Prolly not and either way, could we say instead that you had either a puzzle in which changing one attribute changed the other, or a different scenario with three “conditions” and a different combination of effects?

Could we say instead that you didn’t describe anything tangible and it would be more fun if you could reword both Question and explanation to describe a single situation containing a Question involving English language, rather than some convoluted instance of the logic of puzzles?

Comment: In (software) engineering, we sometimes call these "whack-a-mole" problems - you fix one bit and an issue pops up somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

It’s an *optimisation* problem.

> In mathematics and computer science, an optimization problem is the problem of finding the best solution from all feasible solutions.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_problem)

It’s not enough to modify one of the parameters - the puzzle requires *all* the parameters to be ‘tuned’ in concert to get the global ‘best’ answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is reminiscent of **Nash equilibria**, a concept from game theory. The only difference being that such an equilibrium is normally defined by a number of players who each have a strategy.

If you would view each of your conditions A, B and C as sets of strategies then your current combination of conditions is a Nash equilibrium if you cannot get a better outcome by merely changing the strategy of one of A, B and C.

Wikipedia lists both formal and informal definitions for the Nash equilibrium, I will quote the first part [from the informal one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium#Informal_definition):

> Informally, a strategy profile is a Nash equilibrium if no player can do better by unilaterally changing his or her strategy.

Attribution: "Nash Equilibrium." Wikipedia. April 20, 2018. Accessed April 28, 2018. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium#Informal_definition.